# Getting CKR_TEMPLATE_INCONSISTENT while importing certificate programmatically

Tags: c++, certificate, x509certificate, pki, safenet

I want to programmatically import certificate to safenet dongle. I want to do it in a swift application.

below is my code.

```
void Dongle::importCertificate(char *password, char* enrollmentId, unsigned char * subject, unsigned char * issuer, unsigned char * serialNumber, unsigned char * value ) {
    CK_RV rv = CKR_OK;
    
    CK_BBOOL    bFalse  = CK_FALSE;
    CK_BBOOL    bTrue   = CK_TRUE;
    CK_KEY_TYPE keyType = CKK_RSA;
    
    CK_SESSION_HANDLE hSession = CK_INVALID_HANDLE;
    
    LoadCryptoki(pkcs11_path);
    
    rv = GetFirstSlotId(&slotId);
    rv = C_OpenSession(slotId, (CKF_SERIAL_SESSION | CKF_RW_SESSION), NULL_PTR, NULL_PTR, &hSession);
    
    // We can also use Dongle::generateKeyPairUtil
    CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hPrivateKey = Dongle::getPrivateKeyHandle(hSession, password, enrollmentId);
    
    
    CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hObject;
    
    std::string labelPriv = std::string("private") + enrollmentId;
    CK_UTF8CHAR * labelPrivate = convertToCK_UTF8CHAR(labelPriv); //Label of private key.
    std::string idPriv = std::string(enrollmentId);
    CK_UTF8CHAR * idPrivate = convertToCK_UTF8CHAR(idPriv);
    CK_OBJECT_CLASS  classCertificate = CKO_CERTIFICATE;
    CK_OBJECT_CLASS  typeCertificate = CKC_X_509;
    CK_ATTRIBUTE certificateTemplate[] =
    {
        { CKA_CLASS, &classCertificate, sizeof(classCertificate) },
        { CKA_TOKEN, &bTrue, sizeof(bTrue) },
        { CKA_PRIVATE, &bFalse, sizeof(bFalse) },
        { CKA_MODIFIABLE, &bTrue, sizeof(bTrue) },
        { CKA_LABEL, &labelPrivate, strlen((char *)labelPrivate) },
        { CKA_CERTIFICATE_TYPE, &typeCertificate, sizeof(typeCertificate) },
        { CKA_TRUSTED, &bFalse, sizeof(bFalse) },
        { CKA_SUBJECT, &subject, strlen((char*) subject) },
        { CKA_ID, &idPrivate, strlen((char*)idPrivate) },
        { CKA_ISSUER, &issuer, strlen((char*) issuer) },
        { CKA_SERIAL_NUMBER, &serialNumber, strlen((char*) serialNumber) },
        { CKA_VALUE, &value, strlen((char*) value) }
        
    };
    //CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hObject;
    rv = C_CreateObject( hSession,
                         certificateTemplate,
                         DIM(certificateTemplate),
                         &hObject );
    std::cout << "object handle code: \n";
    std::cout << rv;
    
    if (rv == CKR_OK) {
        std::cout<< "Created object handle"<< hObject<< std::endl;
    }

    
    if (hSession) {
        C_CloseSession(hSession);
        UnloadCryptoki();
    }
    
}
```

I have extracted subjectDN, issuerName, serialNumber and certificate as DER and then sending it here.
But I am getting error code D1(209) which says that CKR_TEMPLATE_INCONSISTENT.